# Next and Previous keypress Jquery

Tags: jquery, keypress

Hi I'd like to make my page scroll to certain divs when the next and previous arrow keys are pressed on the keyboard. I'd like it to specifically go to the next or previous div with the class name "slider-panel".  Here is my html and jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".port-link-container").click(function () {
    $("div.slider-panel").slideUp("slow");
    });

    $("#wr").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 450 }, 'slow');
        $("div#wr-large").slideDown("slow");
    });

    $("#sema").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 450 }, 'slow');
        $("div#sema-large").slideDown("slow");
    });

    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27)
            $("div.slider-panel").slideUp();
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        });

    $(".slider-close").click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
        $("div.slider-panel").slideUp("slow");
    });
});

<div class="toppanel">
    <div id="wr-large" class="slider-panel">
         <div class="slider-content clearfix">
            <div style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;">
                <div class="slider-close"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="wr-large"></div>
                <div class="slider-close"></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="sema-large" class="slider-panel">
        <div class="slider-content clearfix">
            <div style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;">
                <div class="sema-large"></div>
                <div class="slider-close"></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the left and right arrow keys?

Comment: yes i would like it to go to the next div with the class "slider-panel" using the arrow keys

Comment: Can you create a demo on http://www.jsfiddle.net? I can't seem to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking why your current code doesn't work, or looking for help implementing your feature on top of the existing script?  Right now your keyUp function is only looking for the ESC key (27):

http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx

If I were to implement this, I would check for the next/prev keys, and then figure out which div I want to 'focus'.  I would get the global x/y position for that div, then scrollTo those positions.

I know this is a little vague, but let me know if you need help with the code sample.

Comment: yes id like to add the next/prev keys on top of the esc commands. Here is a link to the site it is included in http://norkenguitars.com/new/portfolio.htm.  When you click one of the grey icons a slider comes down, id like to use the next/prev arrows on the keyboard to navigate through the images within this slider rather than having to close and open each image.  Sample code would be very helpful

Comment: if you can provide that example it would be very helpful